# Solve a differential eq with a boundray condtion and plot it

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, list-manipulation, boundary-conditions

I just wanted to know how to plot this for different value of a,b and f (Table[])?

```
       Clear["Global`*"]
       Clear[a, b, f, h, x]
       eqn = {h'[x] == (a*s + (9b^2 /8s -(s+1) f ) x^2 -  3b/2s * h [x]*x^2 + h[x]^2 x^2)/(h[x]* x^3)};
      sol = DSolve[{eqn, h[1] == 1}, h[x], x]
      Plot[h[x] /. sol /. {s->1/2,a -> -0.04, b -> 1, f -> 7/10}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Analytically or numerically?

Comment: firstly, I prefer analytical if it is not possible then numerically.

Comment: Sinc you have received already answers, let me just point out something. I see that you have asked 21 questions, yet you have not accepted any answers. I would like to politely ask you to reconsider that. See [`here`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) also for more details

Answer (score 5):

This can't be solved analytically by Mathematica. One option is to use `ParametricNDSolveValue`

```
ClearAll[a,b,f,h,x,s]
eqn  = h'[x]==(a*s+(9b^2/8s-(s+1) f) x^2-3b/2s*h[x]*x^2+h[x]^2 x^2)/(h[x]*x^3);
bc   = h[1]==1;
vals = {s->1/2,f->7/10};
sol  = DSolve[{eqn/.vals,bc},h[x],x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqn /. vals, bc}, h, {x, 1, 10}, {a, b}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This plots for `a=10` and `b=3`

```
Plot[sol[10, 3][x], {x, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red,  
      GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can make a Manipulate and slider for `a` and slider for `b`. I'll add one soon.

### Version with Manipulate

[image]

```
ClearAll[a, b, f, h, x, s]
eqn = h'[x] == (a*s + (9 b^2/8 s - (s + 1) f) x^2 - 3 b/2 s*h[x]*x^2 +
       h[x]^2 x^2)/(h[x]*x^3);
bc = h[1] == 1;
vals = {s -> 1/2, f -> 7/10};
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqn /. vals, bc}, h, {x, 1, 10}, {a, b}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[sol[a0, b0][x], {x, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray],
 {{a0, 1, "a"}, .1, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b0, 1, "b"}, .1, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a0, b0}
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**   Answer to the original post with a,b,f as parameters, before user changed it.

Didn't get anylytical solution.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqn = (h'[
     x] == (a + (2 b^2 + f) x^2 - 2 b*h[x]*x^2 + h[x]^2 x^2)/(h[x]*
       x^3));
hsol[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ] := 
 h /. Flatten@
   NDSolve[{(h'[
        x] == (a + (2 b^2 + f) x^2 - 2 b*h[x]*x^2 + h[x]^2 x^2)/(h[x]*
          x^3)), h[1] == 1}, h, {x, 1, 10}]

Plot[Evaluate[
  hsol[a, b, f][x] /. {a -> -0.04, b -> 1, f -> 7/10}], {x, 1, 10}]
```